# Python Struct Packing Unpacking

Tags: python

I've two bytes **\x22\x38**. (Read from from a Process Memory so preferably little endian)

I am pretty sure these bytes get converted **0x588**, But don't know how.
I want to know how python struct module can be used to convert \x22\x38 to 0x588.

Comment: What makes you think `\x22\x38` maps to `0x588`? I don't quite see the relationship. `\x22\x38` interpreted as a (signed or unsigned) short would be `0x2238` or `0x3822` if the resulting integer was expressed in hexadecimal.

Comment: Please take a look at this question posted by me  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483473/windows-heap-chunk-header-parsing-and-size-calculation

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't explain why you come to the conclusion that those two bytes make hex 588.

Comment: Actually dt _HEAP_ENTRY 00500000 tells me that first two bytes going to determine size of the chunk and !heap -a 00500000 tells me the size of the same chunk.

Answer (score 1):

There's something else going on if somehow 22<sub>16</sub>/38<sub>16</sub> maps to anything other than 2238<sub>16</sub> or 3822<sub>16</sub>, but in any event:

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = b'\x22\x38'
>>> struct.unpack('<h', data)
(14370,)
>>> struct.unpack('>h', data)
(8760,)
```

Note that `unpack()` returns a tuple. `h` is for s**h**ort (as in a C short), the `<` or `>` sets the endianness. See the [`struct` package docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html) for full info.

Comment: Can you please take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483473/windows-heap-chunk-header-parsing-and-size-calculation. I posted this and they are co-related.

Comment: They may be in your particular case, but it is unrelated to the usage of the `struct` module in Python.