# How to interpret the result of !heap -l from Windbg

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, windbg

I have a 3.5Gb dump file from a process which I suspect that has memory leak. I used Windbg to analyze the dump file and the specific command I used was !heap -l (for leak detection). The result showed that 807258 potential unreachable blocks were detected. However, I don't know how to use the analysis result. The report has the following format:

**Entry | User | Heap | Segment | Size | PrevSize | Unused | Flags**

**00000000002e4190 | 00000000002e41a0 | 0000000000260000 | 0000000000260000 | 210 | 60 | 10 | busy**

**......(the rest of the 807258 rows)**

My understanding is that heap column tells you which heap the leak is coming from but what does Entry and User stand for? I couldn't find any explanation in the online document of Microsoft. Can someone help me understand what does each of these columns mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Entry` is the address of the `HEAP_ENTRY` for that heap allocation. It's undocumented, but looks [something like this](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d4/d93/struct__HEAP__COMMON__ENTRY.html).

You can see how it looks on your system using `dt nt!_HEAP_ENTRY` or even look at that specific heap entry using `dt nt!_HEAP_ENTRY 00000000002e4190`.

Here's the layout of `nt!_HEAP_ENTRY` on my system:

```
0:007> dt nt!_HEAP_ENTRY
ntdll!_HEAP_ENTRY
   +0x000 UnpackedEntry    : _HEAP_UNPACKED_ENTRY
   +0x000 PreviousBlockPrivateData : Ptr64 Void
   +0x008 Size             : Uint2B
   +0x00a Flags            : UChar
   +0x00b SmallTagIndex    : UChar
   +0x008 SubSegmentCode   : Uint4B
   +0x00c PreviousSize     : Uint2B
   +0x00e SegmentOffset    : UChar
   +0x00e LFHFlags         : UChar
   +0x00f UnusedBytes      : UChar
   +0x008 CompactHeader    : Uint8B
   +0x000 ExtendedEntry    : _HEAP_EXTENDED_ENTRY
   +0x000 Reserved         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x008 FunctionIndex    : Uint2B
   +0x00a ContextValue     : Uint2B
   +0x008 InterceptorValue : Uint4B
   +0x00c UnusedBytesLength : Uint2B
   +0x00e EntryOffset      : UChar
   +0x00f ExtendedBlockSignature : UChar
   +0x000 ReservedForAlignment : Ptr64 Void
   +0x008 Code1            : Uint4B
   +0x00c Code2            : Uint2B
   +0x00e Code3            : UChar
   +0x00f Code4            : UChar
   +0x00c Code234          : Uint4B
   +0x008 AgregateCode     : Uint8B
```

---

`User` is simply the start of the allocation as returned by [`RtlAllocateHeap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlallocateheap) or [`HeapAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx).

It's usually equal to the `Entry` address plus `sizeof(_HEAP_ENTRY)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also, what dose size mean here? Is that the size of actual allocation returned by RtlAllocateHeap() or HeapAlloc()?

Comment: @OptimusPrime The `Size` field is taken directly out of `nt!_HEAP_ENTRY`. It's not necessarily the size that was requested, but the size of the allocation the heap manager decided to return, including the space taken by the `nt!_HEAP_ENTRY` itself. This allows some wiggle room for the heap to find a free entry that is close in size, but not necessarily exact.

Comment: (continued) It also allows for some optimisations like keeping all entries of a particular size bucketed together, as is the case for a [low-fragmentation heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366750). (Note: The tricky bit of extracting the `Size` field from `nt!_HEAP_ENTRY` is that it's encoded. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28501565/1020072).

Comment: When I use !heap -l to find leak, one of the heap entry returned is 00000000002e73d0 on heap 0000000000270000. But when I use !heap -a 0000000000270000 to find all heap entries on this heap, this entry is not listed. Do you know why the leaked entry is not shown there?

Comment: @OptimusPrime Just a guess, but if `!heap -l` shows `LFH` (it's a low-fragmentation heap entry) in the flags column, then `!heap -a` won't print anything about that entry.